# Pageable with nested list spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I'm using a pageable object to return an object `ResponseDto` which contains a list of record

the object is in this form:

```java
public class ResponseDto{
   private String prop1;
   private String prop2;
   private List<NestedDto> nestedDto;
}
```

i can get with 2 different queries both `Page<ResponseDto>` and `List<NestedDto>` but i have to get inside the pageable content and update it to create the nested object.

**EDIT: More info**

so in what i'm doing is:

```java
Page<ResponseDto> response = repository.findRecord()
```

and

```java
List<NestedDto> nested = otherRepository.findNestedRecord(someProp)
```

so it will be something like this

```java
for(ResponseDto el: response.getContent()){
   el.setNestedDto(otherRepository.findNestedRecord(el.getSomeProp));
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to create this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't done anything wrong with this implementation.

```
{
   "prop1": "anyProp1",
   "prop2": "anyProp2",
   "nestedDto": [
       {
           "attr1": "anyAttr1",
           "attr2": "anyAttr2"
       },
       {
           "attr1": "anyAttr1"
           "attr2": "anyAttr2"
       }
   ]
}
```

Maybe naming can change but it is pseudo so it is not important.

Also you can sort and filter by (nestedDto.attr1 or nestedDto.attr2)

Comment: Thank you for you answer i've added some more information to describe the problem